# Facebook + OpenId Connect

Tags: facebook, oauth, openid, openid-connect

I have been reading about OpenId Connect. The idea of having a federated identity that may be shared between many sites seems great.

I was wondering if Facebook accepts OpenId Connect? I am not asking about using OAUTH to authorization via the Facebook Connect service, but, bypassing Facebook authorization step and have Facebook automatically grant my users access via the users OpenId Connect session token.

He are the hypothetical steps I would like to take.

- Use signs into my site.
- Site issues OpenId Connect Token
- User navigates to Facebook website
- Facebook reads the OpenId Connect token, and grants user access

  - (Facebook skips login prompt)

Is this possible? Also I may be missing some steps (writing a cookie) as I am in the early get-my-mind-around-it stage.

Moreover, I have read that Facebook Connect is a *competing* technology and as such it would make perfect sense if OpenId Connect was not implemented by Facebook.

If anyone could shed any light, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will provide your application with a token, because your application will probably trust facebook (as a IP), and certainly not the other way around. So the user is logged into facebook, you can also automatically login to your application, but probably he will see a confirmation screen, telling him that your application wants to access his user information (identity) and his account, enumerating the services/information which the application wants access to, and it is possible that he will be able to select/deselect them. I don't think that Facebook has yet support for OpenID Connect...